# arrayadapter.clear() deletes underlying data

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

i got the following Problem. I got a listview and two buttons. At the start of the Fragment some data is stored in 2 Arraylists. At first the content of the first Arraylist is shown in the listview which works fine. When the use clicks the first button the ListView shows the second ArrayList. Which works fine for the user but as soon as i call adapter.clear(). The first Arraylist got deleted. Therefor he cant switch back to the first list by clicking on the first button. I never delete the Arraylist so i wonder why adapter.clear() does it. Any help would be nice. Code underneath.

```
public class MessagesFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<Message> outbound;
private ArrayList<Message> inbound;
private MessageAdapter messageadapter;
private int box;
private View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container,
            false);
    outbound = new ArrayList<Message>();
    inbound = new ArrayList<Message>();
    this.rootView = rootView;
    box = 0;
    messageadapter = new MessageAdapter(getActivity(),
                    R.layout.item_message, inbound);
    ((ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_message))
                    .setAdapter(messageadapter);
    initializeListeners();
    return rootView;
}

private void initializeListeners() {
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.rb_message_inbox).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showBox(0);
                }
            });

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.rb_message_outbox).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showBox(1);
                }
            });     
}

private void showBox(int box) {
    messageadapter.clear();
    switch (box) {
    case 0:
        messageadapter.addAll(inbound);
        break;
    case 1:
        messageadapter.addAll(outbound);
        break;
    }
    this.box = box;
    messageadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

So at the beginning the list gets populated with the ArrayList inbound. But when showbox(1) is called inbound gets deleted as soon as messageadapter.clear() gets called.
iutbound will be shown but with calling showbox(0) after that inbound wont because its empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happened because your class member arraylist is the same reference as you set into your adapter. Add data to your adapter by

```
adapter.addAll(new ArrayList<Message>(inbound);
```

Comment: thanks but it only worked when i changed this too;

    messageadapter = new MessageAdapter(getActivity(),      R.layout.item_message, new ArrayList<Message>(inbound));

Comment: Thanks, it worked. the problem was due to clear method. it clears the Arraylist each time it called.